# Select specific columns in a PySpark dataframe to improve performance

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark, apache-spark-sql

Working with Spark dataframes imported from Hive, sometimes I end up with several columns that I don't need. Supposing that I don't want to filter them with

```
df = SqlContext.sql('select cols from mytable')
```

and I'm importing the entire table with

```
df = SqlContext.table(mytable)
```

does a `select` and subsequent `cache` improves performance/decrease memory usage, like

```
df = df.select('col_1', 'col_2', 'col_3')
df.cache()
df.count()
```

or is just waste of time? I will do lots of operations and data manipulations on `df`, like `avg`, `withColumn`, etc.

Comment: Cache helps a lot, so it shall boost the performance.

Comment: But is it worthwhile to do a select beforehand?

Comment: Yes it does, if you don't need other columns in the following steps - so you'll have only needed columns in cache

Answer (score 2):

It is certainly a good practice but it is rather unlikely to result in a performance boost unless you try to pass data through Python RDD or do something similar. If certain columns are not required to compute the output optimizer should automatically infer projections and push these as early as possible in the execution plan.

Also it is worth noting that using `df.count()` after `df.cache()` will be useless most of the time (if not always). In general `count` is rewritten by the optimizer as

```
SELECT SUM(1) FROM table
```

so what is typically requested from the source is:

```
SELECT 1 FROM table
```

Long story short there is nothing useful to cache here.

Comment: Thanks again, @zero323! I was thinking more on the lines of doing a count just after a cache to commit the cache operation and check a few numbers as a byproduct. I noticed that sometimes doing a `select` makes the performance *worse* before the cache.

Comment: Well, reasoning about cache in Spark SQL is relatively hard and tricks like `cache` / `count` are not the best idea. You can see some performance boost which is not related to Spark caching when data is for example memory mapped but IMHO it is more a ritual then anything else.

Answer (score 1):

IMO it makes sense to filter them beforehand:

```
df = SqlContext.sql('select col_1, col_2, col_3 from mytable')
```

so you won't waste resources...

If you can't do it this way, then you can do it as you did it...